# How to calculate the autocorrelation coefficient of multi-dimensional time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation

The autocorrelation coefficient formula of one-dimensional time series is as belows:

$r_k = {\sum\limits^{n-k}_{l=1}}(x_1-\bar x)(x_{l+k}-\bar x)/{\sum\limits^n_{l=1}}(x_l-\bar x)^2$

I want to know how to calculate the autocorrelation coefficient of multi-dimensional time series, such as(five dimensions):

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 6
2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 9
3 4 5 6 8
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have not enough reputation to comment.

Correlation for multidimensional data is tricky, if all your dimensions are of the same importance (if you have no dependent variable). If You have 3 variables of the same importance H(height), W (weight) and F(foot size) for example, then if response will be H or response will be W you will have different correlation.

I would suggest the following: as correlation represents amount of variation explained by predictors, you may use another methods to calculate explained variance.

It is possible to perform PCA and use explained by 1st or 1st-2nd etc variance.